# How to CREATE TABLE AS in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to redshift (but not new to SQL). I've created a somewhat complex query joining lots of tables together that is working, however when using our visualization tool (metabase) it's having to run the query to make the base table 15 times (once for each visualization) and it takes a long time.

It makes sense to me to just create the base table in redshift and have it set to update with each time our data updates (once every 12 hours) and then query from there, rather than having metabase create it on demand.

The only thing is, I simply can't find where to execute a 'CREATE TABLE AS' command nor how to make it a scheduled job.

Does anybody know:

1. Where I can execute a CREATE TABLE AS command in Redshift?
2. How can I set this to be recurring on a schedule?
3. What is the minimum level of permissions I need to do these tasks?

I've been searching AWS docs but they have been less than helpful. I have a feeling I might not have high enough permissions to see the option, which is frustrating.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT ... should work just in Redshift.  However, this won't set the dist and sort keys for the table, along with other attributes, so you may not get all the performance you desire when using the table.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html

You can schedule queries to run on Redshift using the console (web).  See info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-schedule-query.html  Personally I prefer to write Lambda functions to perform scheduled tasks on Redshift as this gives a wide range of functionality (on Redshift and with other AWS services) and opens up the world of Step Functions.

I assume you are talking about database permissions.  You will need to have write permission to the schema in order to create a new table.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I have no experience with lambda functions, but am happy to have an reason to learn something new. 
I thought I would need specific permissions to access the db through the query editor, since the options didn't auto populate, but I guess I need the db credentials rather than a specific access level.